# What are real life use cases in embedded systems for alignment control introduced in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, embedded, memory-alignment

***Question background:***

Yesterday I watched Scott Meyers talk about [Support for Embedded Programming in C++11 and C++14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-tA17slViE). He pointed out five features introduced in C++11 and two features introduced in C++14 especially interesting for the embedded developers however he elaborated only about `auto` and `constexpr` in this talk.

**Features especially interesting for the embedded developers according to Scott Meyers.**

**C++11:**

- alignment control
- `constexpr`
- `std::array`
- underlying types for enums
- `std::function`

**C++14 features:**

- relaxed rules for `constexpr` functions
- binary literals

***Question:***

My question to you is about alignment control.
**What are the real life use cases making this feature really nice to have with emphasize to embedded systems?**

I understand that we will concentrate on [`std::align`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) and [`std::aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage).
I imagine that this feature might be very useful when we allocate big collection of POD objects and we want to read and write them fast with native data transfer for the given CPU architecture (e.g. 4 bytes for x86). Right? What other useful use cases we have for this feature? **I would love to see some real life examples.**

Comment: `optional`, `expected`, `variant` all rely on it.  Do they count?

Comment: Too broad.Why not google yourself why alignment is used and use your own wits?

Comment: @Yakk I'm not familiar with this. I'm googling and studying it. I will get back to you soon.

Comment: @Olaf I did it. However what is bothering me the most is usefulness of std::align func, because I do not consider cppreference example as a real life example. What's more I do not see huge benefit of enforcing single object alignment - probably compiler aligns it anyways to CPU data bus width (that's the behavior I observed through out my experiments). I see a reason to make aligned storage though. I want to learn something new and that's the reason I asked the question. I'm familiar with C++98 but I'm still learning new standard. I'm also hopping that somebody will share something new to me.

Comment: As an **application** programmer you likely will have little use, I agree. However, there are quite some rationales to be found on the net. Note: C11 also adds alignment support. IMO, this is the better language for bare-metal anyway and you might find more practical use-cases here.

Comment: Wanting to know something is a good reason to ask a question, but stack overflow aims for narrow, answerable questions more than "tell me all about X".

Comment: @yakk The need for nearly everything to be `constexpr` in [`optional`](https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2/blob/master/include/stl2/optional.hpp) and [`variant`](https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2/blob/master/include/stl2/variant.hpp) makes it impossible to use `aligned_storage` in their implementation.

Comment: @Casey heh.  Well, my quick homebrew implementation doesn't support `constexpr` at this point, so I didn't notice.

Comment: I suspect what Scott Myers is alluding to is being able to declare a `struct` that maps onto memory mapped IO in a reliable and portable way